# Angular complains about unknown provider with this simple directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am adding this `my-resize` directive:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" my-resize="resize">
    <p>width:{{width}} height:{{height}}</p>
</body>
```

,where `resize` is a function defined in the `MainCtrl` controller (see: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8ckbLbRcA6P6XqzU1fx)

The directive is very simple:

```
app.directive('myResize', function($scope){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          ngResize: '&'
        },
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attr){
            $scope.$on('resize', ngResize);

        }
    };
});
```

Yet I am getting **Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider** and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myResize', ['$window', function($window) {
 return {
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
   scope.onResize = function() {
    scope.height = $window.innerHeight;
        scope.width = $window.innerWidth;
   }
   scope.onResize();

   angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
    scope.onResize();
    scope.$apply();
   })
  }
 }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    
    <div my-resize>
    
    window height: {{height}}  
    window width:{{width}}<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

$scope can not be injected to directive. You have change the code to inject $scope in controller of directive.

$scope is not a service($scopeProvider is not exist in angular js) it is something special that is injected by angular itself into the controller as a child of $rootScope.

so you cannot explicitly inject it in service,directive...etc.

you can inject it explicitly in the controller of direcitve (not directly to the directive).

http://plnkr.co/edit/mxEMXxIKOrJtRqQa4IQb?p=preview

Comment: Okay, but when I remove `$scope` from the directive I am getting "Multiple Directive Resource Contention" error, for I have two isolated scopes.

Comment: If you want to find height and width you can use my directive which i have attached in snippet. At a same time, I will try to solve your directive and will send you back

Comment: Looks like you brought me to a better understanding. The problem is the scope indeed, when I use controller and the directive in the same DOM element, and this may be Angular limitation. What I need now is in the `link` function get the `attr`, which holds the `my-resize` attribute and convert its value to a function call. That should do. I am upping your answer, but I won't mark it as a solution, for it it is not resolving the problem yet. Thank you, Ananth. I will now work on this callback.